# how to bulk insert in mongodb using golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, glide-golang

Node js example:

```
const bulk = db.items.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find( { status: "D" } ).update( { $set: { status: "I", points: "0" } } );
bulk.find( { item: null } ).update( { $set: { item: "TBD" } } );
bulk.execute();
```

How to implement this in **golang**

I have to insert bulk users on users collection on this email is a unique key, so I want to insert all users or if users exist then update them.

Comment: Provide what you've tried and what problems you have. Aim for a [mcve]. If you don't know where to start, check out `Collection.BulkWrite()`.

Comment: @icza I have to insert bulk users on users collection on this email is a unique key, so I want to insert all users or if users exist then update them.